# Hide or show dropdown on the basis of textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a registration form in my ASP.NET Core MVC site, I am asking user to provide zip code along with other user information.

If there is only one county associated with that zip code, I don't want to show dropdown for selecting county, else if more than one county is there, I want to show dropdown to user for selecting county.

```
public class RegisterUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
<form asp-action="Register" method="post" asp-controller="User" asp-antiforgery="true">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label col-sm-3"></label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" />
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label col-sm-3"></label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" />
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" asp-validation-for="LastName"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BirthDate" class="control-label col-sm-3"></label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input asp-for="BirthDate" class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" />
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" asp-validation-for="BirthDate"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label col-sm-3"></label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input asp-for="EmailAddress" class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" />
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" asp-validation-for="EmailAddress"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ZipCode" class="control-label col-sm-3"></label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input asp-for="ZipCode" class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" />
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" asp-validation-for="ZipCode"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 button-holder">
            <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="button-green btn btn-default pull-right" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What to do in this scenario? I have not added my dropdown logic in this yet.

Comment: is it wpf ? winforms ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  What type of application it is and what is the try and difficulty implementing this?

Comment: @staticvoidmain I have updated my question.

Comment: plz show some html.

Comment: @Sonali -Thanks. few suggestions, Country cannot be a string, it could be string[] or a list<string>.  We cannot change input type dynamically, show/hide based on the count of elements will help.

Comment: this might be helpful to dynamically add dropdown, Link :  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-core-mvc-with-new-tag-helpers/

Answer (score 1):

You simply need some JavaScript and potentially AJAX. Basically, you bind to the input/blur event of the zip code input. Your delegate will then either hide the dropdown or show the dropdown based on some type of logic.

To determine what countries "belong" to a particular zip code, you'll need an endpoint (ASP.NET Core action) that can accept the zip code as a param and then use that to look up associated countries. You then return that list of countries as JSON.

You'll then, of course, need to request this endpoint, passing the zip code, via AJAX. Your "success" delegate, then, would take the returned JSON and use that to build out your dropdown options and then display the dropdown, assuming there's more than one item. If there's only one item, you either do nothing or hide the dropdown if it's currently being shown.

You might consider using a library like Knockout.js, Vue.js, etc. as it takes alot of the manual work out. Long and short, do some research, make an attempt, and if you have additional questions or run into issues, you can come back and ask another question about that.

Comment: In model, do I have to mark County as Required or not?

Comment: Suppose after getting all the counties, if I append one drop down dynamically then in that case I need to have required check there. So I have to use javascript for that? If I found no county then how I will set its value in model.